# WordPress 3.9 Multisite db connection error

Tags: php, wordpress, wpmu, wordpress-3.9

I have a ZendFW application and WPMU installed. Admins at Zend app has an interface where they can create a new MU site.

I included `wp-load.php` and then called `wpmu_create_blog` and so on...

Once I updated the WP to 3.9 I got error establishing database connection.

This test code works OK with 3.8 but gives db error when tried WP 3.9.

**blog38** is WP 3.8

```
<?php 

include "../blog38/wp-load.php";

global $wpdb;
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($wpdb->tables());
?>
```

**blog39** is WP 3.9

```
<?php 

include "../blog39/wp-load.php";

global $wpdb;
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($wpdb->tables());
?>
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? How to solve this connection error?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this Ivan? Also what error did you get in 3.9? (add error to post)

Comment: Did you notice this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141578/3-9-breaks-multisite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted it on WordPress discussion and submitted a ticket as well. The problem is in ms-setting.php file with new way they set $path and $current_site->path variables. In WP 3.8.3 they had 
`$current_site->path = $path = PATH_CURRENT_SITE;`

and in WP 3.9 they set

`$current_site->path = PATH_CURRENT_SITE;`

and $path is determined by the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable. So when you load wp-load.php file inside your application (and wordpress is in subdirectory) you have $path and $current_site->path variable different which ends up in no blog defined case, which gives Database connection error.

Current workaround is to override `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/blog/';` before loading `wp-load.php`

More information can be found:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-39-multisite-db-connection-error
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27999